# NGINX and SPRINGBOOT in DOCKER container GOT 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: docker, nginx

I deployed my springboot project in docker container opening port 8080 as well as an nginx server opening port 80
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWa9Q.png)

When I use
**curl http://localhost:8080/heya/index**
it returns normally

But when I use
**curl http://localhost/heya/index**
hoping I can reach from nginx proxy,it failed. And I checked the log, it says

**24#24: *11 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.17.0.1, server: , request: "GET /heya/index HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/heya/index", host: "localhost"**

Here is my nginx.conf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mato.png)

I cannot figure it out and need help.

Comment: Add the configuration and the output as text not as link to an image

Comment: In the future, please post all relevant code and errors as text, not images.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got the answer!!

I ran nginx container and webapp container using host network mode, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

> 111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

is saying Nginx can't connect to the upstream server.

Your

```
proxy_pass http://heya;
```

is telling Nginx that the upstream is talking the HTTP protocol [on the default port 80] on the hostname `heya`. Unless you're running multiple containers in the same Compose network, it's unlikely that the hostname would be `heya`.

If the Java application is running on port 8080 inside the same container, talking the HTTP protocol, the correct `proxy_pass` would be

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
```

(since `localhost` in the container's view is the container itself).

Comment: I tried it just now, but it still doesn't work and returns the 502 Bad Gateway as well. Actually the intention I put upstream {} there is to reserve a place for future servers. Since I define the name there, maybe I can use it behind... But I am not sure it's correct

Comment: Oh I find the reason. I just tried ping localhost:8080/heya/index in nginx container, it just refused me, but how can I place them in the same network?